# InstagramKit (ios) Login Authentication Issues

Tags: ios, sdk, instagram

I'm trying to use Shyambhat's InstagramKit (from the DEV branch) and I just can't get Instagram to redirect to the app (and to the section of code that should catch the redirect URL) after I login no matter what I do.

In my Info.Plist I have:

```
InstagramAppRedirectURL: app://
```

And also on instagram I have:

```
Redirect URI: app://
```

It's always identical... it never works. (and I've tried [myclientID]://authorize and a bunch of other things.)

I get the error "Error: The page could not be loaded If you have cookies..."

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Do we see the light of day?");
    InstagramKitLoginScope scope = InstagramKitLoginScopeRelationships | InstagramKitLoginScopeComments | InstagramKitLoginScopeLikes;
    NSURL *authURL = [[InstagramEngine sharedEngine] authorizationURLForScope:scope];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:authURL]];


}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"Did instagram make it here?");
    NSError *error;
    if ([[InstagramEngine sharedEngine] receivedValidAccessTokenFromURL:request.URL error:&error]) {
        // success!
        NSLog(@"Instagram login successful");
    }
    return YES;
}
```

We do "see the light of day". I make it to the login screen... I login... but it never makes it to "Did instagram make it here?"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said... it was never making it to the BOOL webView.  Turns out I just needed to explicitly set the delegate in viewWillAppear:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    _webView.delegate = self;
}
```

Problem solved.